# Capistrano deploy fails when upgrade ruby version in rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run `cap production deploy` in my rails project directory, I get error like this:

```
INFO[6be9dff4] Running RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.1 /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --binstubs /var/www/example.com/shared/bin --path /var/www/example.com/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet on example.com
DEBUG[6be9dff4] Command: cd /var/www/example.com/releases/20140624143014 && ( RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.1 RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.1 /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --binstubs /var/www/example.com/shared/bin --path /var/www/example.com/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet )
DEBUG[6be9dff4]     Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/www/example.com/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/cache/rake-10.3.2.gem
DEBUG[6be9dff4]     An error occurred while installing rake (10.3.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
DEBUG[6be9dff4]     Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.3.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So I login server and change user to deploy user, then run command like this:

```
$ su - deployer
Password: 
deployer@server ~$ cd /var/www/example.com/releases/20140624143014 && ( RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.1 RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.1 /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --binstubs /var/www/example.com/shared/bin --path /var/www/example.com/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet )
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/www/example.com/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/cache/rake-10.3.2.gem
An error occurred while installing rake (10.3.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.3.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

`rbenv` and `ruby` is installed like this:

```
$ rbenv versions
  system
  2.0.0-p451
* 2.1.1 (set by /usr/local/rbenv/version)
```

I'm tring to deploy from `LinuxMint16` to `CentOS 6.5` with `Capistrano 3` and prior deploy was successful when I used `2.0.0-p451`.

How and what should I check to find out what causes error?